# how to remove number of share on facebook share button

Tags: javascript, share

how to remove number of share on facebook share button

This is the code

```html
<body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1074461072666302";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
   <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.itmam.com/cpbank/index.html" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true">
      <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
   </div>
</body>
```

here's the example shows what i mean 
[image: example]

i want to remove  0 from the button .

Thank you .

Comment: You want just button without number of shares even it is >0?

Comment: i don't need any number on the button

Comment: see my answer below, it may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just show the share button without number of shares, you can use  data-layout="button" instead of  data-layout="button_count". please see the below code

```html
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1074461072666302";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    
    
    
    
    
     <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.itmam.com/cpbank/index.html" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="true">
     <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a>
     </div>
```